# Android Multi Screen Support - Density & Size Qualifiers

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, android-studio

I have 420 dpi phone density screen. But when i change the display from Normal to either Small or Large or Larger, dpi value gets changed. how to design UI for supporting all screens and which qualifier should be used correspondingly.

I used absolute values in dimens.xml, android scale the values to corresponding density but it does not produce proper UI as expected.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:cardview="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/profileCard"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    cardview:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
    cardview:cardElevation="6dp"
    cardview:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
    cardview:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    cardview:contentPadding="0dp"
    tools:targetApi="lollipop">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/artistLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/artistCoverLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/youtube_thumbnail_background">

            <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeThumbnailView
                android:id="@+id/profileCoverThumbnail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:alpha="0.62"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/mCoverImage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="160dp"
                android:background="@drawable/youtube_thumbnail_background"
                android:alpha="0.62" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@null"
                android:src="@mipmap/play" />

        </FrameLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/artistDetailLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/artistCoverLayout"
            android:background="#f9f9f9">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/profile_image"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/profileCoverThumbnail"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_emp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/profile_image"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/profile_image"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/profileName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/profileCoverThumbnail"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8.9dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="7.4dp"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/profile_image"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/profile_image"
                    android:text="Name"
                    android:textColor="@color/artistTitleColor"
                    android:textSize="18.7sp" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8.9dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="7.4dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_location" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/profileLocation"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:text="City"
                        android:textColor="#4a4a4a"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <RatingBar
                    android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:rating="3"
                    android:stepSize="1"
                    android:maxWidth="8.7dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8.9dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="7.4dp"
                    android:theme="@style/RatingBar"
                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.RatingBar.Small"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/genreLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/artistDetailLayout"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10.5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="17.9dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/genretitle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8.6dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="9dp"
                    android:text="Genres"
                    android:textColor="@color/artistTitleColor"
                    android:textSize="13.3sp" />

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/separator"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:background="#f2f2f2" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/skillLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/genreLayout"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="2"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10.5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="17.9dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/skilltitle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="9.3dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="9dp"
                    android:text="Skills"
                    android:textColor="@color/artistTitleColor"
                    android:textSize="13.3sp" />

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/separatorSkill"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:background="#f2f2f2" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/mVisibilityLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="3dp"
            android:paddingTop="3dp"
            android:paddingLeft="23dp"
            android:paddingRight="14dp"
            android:background="#f6f6f6">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/mVisibilityTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Visibility"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textColor="#4a4a4a"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
                android:id="@+id/mVisibilitySwitch"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"/>
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: if you want my advice to support all screen avoid set static number in height or width of any view , make this static numbers for margin , padding right left only

Comment: Avoid using hard-coded sizes from dimen.xml for UI, use wrap_content and weight instead so that UI can scale itself on different devices accordingly.

Comment: @rajesh but UI is not properly aligned as expected, more empty spaces are coming while scaling

Answer (score 1):

Make use of linear layout with weightsum and weight properties. it will dynamically changes it's height and width as per the screen size. :)

Try this

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="160dp">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/artistCoverLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent">

        <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeThumbnailView
            android:id="@+id/profileCoverThumbnail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:alpha="0.62"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/mCoverImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:alpha="0.62" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This might help

Comment: I have use linear layout with vertical orientation. First element is youtube video player. Blank space is coming in youtube player view

Comment: post layout file so that i can help @Jay

Comment: also post snapshot where the issues exists

Comment: i have added code. A brown layer around the player view

Comment: snapshot for the same

Answer (score 0):

Create folders to support multi screen design, like

```
                layout-sw300dp,
                layout-sw330dp,
                layout-sw480dp,
                layout-sw600dp,
                layout-sw720dp.
```

And create values folder

```
                values-sw300dp,
                values-sw330dp,
                values-sw480dp,
                values-sw600dp,
                values-sw720dp.
```

Place your activities in all layouts folder and mention dimens.xml in every values folder.

Comment: 480dp is standard density which is corresponding to XXHDPI, but how you determine 300 and 330 dp?

Comment: there are some resolution like Micromax AQ4501 which support 300dp and Moto E2 support 330 dp.

Comment: I have tested with oneplus 3t when its normal density is 420dpi but when we change small display size it changes to 380dpi. How to sort this out??

Comment: basically what android does in background, its look for equivalent screen design resolution, if not found it will move to lower resolution.

Comment: you mean to say, we need to create layout for all dpi's?

Comment: this will cover almost all screen resolution.. layout-sw300dp, layout-sw330dp, layout-sw480dp, layout-sw600dp, layout-sw720dp.

Comment: how you are calculating smallest width?

Answer (score 0):

You can put the drawables in different folders like by defauld drawable and drwable-xhdpi etc, and in the xml you don't need to give static size of any view use wrap content or match parent instead of static sizes, also one more thing try to use CSS if you can so that image will not blur if it is on high resolution.

Hope it will help you.